# Does every $\alpha$-normal ordered Banach space have minimal upper bounds?

Tags: banach-spaces, positivity

Let $\alpha>0$ and $X$ be an $\alpha$-normal (meaning, for $x,y\in X$,
$0\leq x\leq y$ implies $\|x\|\leq\alpha\|y\|$) ordered Banach space
with closed generating cone $X_{+}$. If $X$ is reflexive, then every
pair of elements from $X$ has a minimal upper bound, i.e., for $x,y\in X$,
there exists some $z\in X$ with $\{x,y\}\leq z$, such that $\{x,y\}\leq w\leq z$ implies
$w=z$. One can show this using Zorn's lemma and the fact that order
intervals are weakly compact (since they are convex, closed and norm
bounded, and the space is reflexive).

> My question is whether there exists a non-reflexive space $X$ where
>   not every pair of elements has a minimal upper bound, or can the
>   reflexivity requirement be dropped?

I couldn't see any way of attacking this without reflexivity, so I started thinking about counter examples. Of course, all Banach lattices are immediately disqualified from potential counterexamples. The best hope I had for an example was something like $X:=\mathbb{R}\oplus_{1}C_{0}(\mathbb{R})$
with the (ice-cream) cone $X_{+}:=\{(t,f)\in X:t\geq\|f\|_{\infty}\}$,
but every pair of elements turns out to have a minimal upper bound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the reflexivity assumption cannot be dropped.

The following simple example (due to Tony Wickstead) is a 1-normal non-reflexive space with closed and generating cone, where there exists a pair of elements without minimal upper bound:

> Let $X$ be the space of all convergent sequences where $x_n\to (x_1+x_2)/2$, ordered by the standard cone (pointwise). Then it is easily seen that the elements $0\in X$ and $(1,-1,0,0,0,\dots)\in X$ has no minimal upper bound.